# How can I find an element from jquery.cache object which jquery uses for data storing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a way to find the element of stored data on jQuery.cache object.

As you may now jQuery stores data as following syntax:

```
$('#idOfTheSelector').data('dataKey','dataValue);
```

jQuery stores this data in `$.cache` object as ;

```
$.cache[1].data.dataKey = 'dataValue';
```

my question is:

- how jQuery associates the data with the element? and
- Can I find a associated element of stored data?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `$('#idOfTheSelector').data('dataKey')`? It will return you whatever your stored in it.

Comment: my english is not perfect. Did I write something wrong not for sure but if I did for the correction; I want to find the element of the stored data not the data itself.

Comment: You mean you have the `dataKey` and you want to find out which element this `dataKey` is associate with?

Comment: I kind of... and not just dataKey I know the exact location of the data. I mean location of the data in the $.cache object. e.g: $.cache[1].data.dataKey1 $.cache[4].data.dataKey3 ...